# How to get rails simple form to work with Bootstrap range slider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, forms, simple-form, bootstrap-slider

I have two fields `start_time` and `end_time` that I want to update when submitting the form. I want it to work with the slider so basically min handle with set the `start_time` and max handle will set the `end_time`

I have the `slider_input.rb` from https://github.com/glyph-fr/simple_form_extension

```
class SliderInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    input_html_options[:class] << 'form-control'
    input_html_options[:data] ||= {}
    input_html_options[:data][:'simple-form-slider'] = true

    [:min, :max, :step, :orientation, :range, :value].each do |key|
      if options.key?(key)
        input_html_options[:data][:"slider-#{ key }"] = options[key]
      end
    end

    input_html_options[:data][:'slider-value'] ||= object.send(attribute_name)

    if options[:disabled]
      input_html_options[:data][:'slider-enabled'] = false
    end

    if options[:ticks]
      input_html_options[:data][:ticks] = options[:ticks].to_json
    end

    @builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
  end
end
```

And in my `_form.html.slim` it looks something like this

```
=f.input_field :start_time, as: :slider
```

Right now the value is not saved into the database after I submitted the form. Also, is there a way to hook up the `start_time` and `end_time` into one input field to work with the range slider?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: @Mugur'Bud'Chirica Not quite yet, I got the data saved to DB but I had to parse the values on the rails side to get start and end time. Still need to hook up the min and max slider handle with start_time and end_time